# Макрос поиска английских слов и подкрашивание их цветом

Tags: excel, vba

Добрый день, помогите разобраться с макросом:

```vb
Sub Color_RUS_LAT() ' RU [color=green]Balck[/color], EN - [color=red]Blue[/color] '
If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
Dim iCell As Range, rRange As Range, i%, ASCII%, iColor%
On Error GoTo eXXit
Set rRange = Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
If rRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each iCell In rRange
  For i = 1 To Len(iCell)
    ASCII = Asc(Mid(iCell, i, 1))
    If (ASCII >= 192 And ASCII <= 255) Then iColor = 1 'Color RU
    If (ASCII >= 65 And ASCII <= 90) Or (ASCII >= 97 And ASCII <= 122) Then iColor = 5 'Color EN
    iCell.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = iColor
  Next i
Next iCell
rRange.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
eXXit: End Sub
```

Макрос ищет английские и русские слова и маркирует их цветом, проблема в том что ищет он только на одном листе и при выделении, а хочется чтобы он отрабатывал на все листы.

Подскажите как это сделать, заранее спасибо

Comment: *хочется чтобы он отрабатывал на все листы* `For Each oneSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets: oneSheet.Activate: обработка листа ; Next`. Ну и желательно отключить обновление экрана и восстановить по завершении текущий лист.

Comment: @ Akina, выделять не обязательно, работа с объектами медленная.

Comment: @Артем, в листах использовать весь пользовательский диапазон или конкретный диапазон/столбец?

Comment: Не совсем понял куда это вставлять, если подскажите буду признателен, да используется весь диапазон.

Comment: @vikttur, да, но это скорее относится к автору вопорса, чем комментария.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Sub Color_RUS_LAT()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rRng As Range, rCell As Range
Dim j As Long, ASCII As Long, lColor As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With sht
            Set rRng = .UsedRange

            For Each rCell In rRng
                For j = 1 To Len(rCell)
                    ASCII = Asc(Mid(rCell, j, 1))

                    Select Case ASCII
                    Case Is > 190: lColor = 3 ' Color RU
                    Case 65 To 90: lColor = 5 ' Color EN
                    Case 97 To 122: lColor = 5 ' Color EN
                    Case Else: lColor = 0
                    End Select

                    rCell.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = lColor
                Next j
            Next rCell
        End With
    Next sht

    Set rRng = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Макрос (как и показанный автором) красит не слова, а каждый символ отдельно.
Если нужно выделять слова, обработку можно ускорить: определять код первой буквы слова и длину слова.

Comment: Спасибо большущее!!!! :)

Comment: См. измененный. С *Select Case* читабельнее. И добавлен черный цвет для других символов

Comment: @Qwertiy, я всегда объявление переменных записываю без отступа. Так этот блок отделяется от основного тела кода. Если это была единственная правка, то она не нужна.

Comment: @vikttur, нет, главным было добавление `<!-- language: lang-vb -->`, из-за чего подсветка поменялась на бейсиковскую. Заодно подвинул объявления переменных и убрал апострофы в конце комментариев (я так понимаю, они там стояли, чтобы подсветка не разваливалась). Кстати, дифф удобно смотреть в режиме _разметка в две колонки_. В других режимах видно, что подсветка другая стала, из-за чего выделен весь код как изменившийся. А переменные можешь подвинуть обратно, если тебе так больше нравится. Я их обычно пустой строкой отделяю. PS: Автоинформирование о комментарии не сработало.

Comment: А нет, сработало... Я невнимательный :(

Comment: Да, возможно,... Не  проконтролировал подсветку после вставки кода. Спасибо.